# Desktop Win10 Toast Notification active callback not firing

Tags: c#, wpf, desktop, windows-10-desktop

The question is that: I have a **WPF** application and want to send a Win10 Style notification.
I searched all the website I know and find the MSDN way to do that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/send-local-toast-desktop.
But unfortunately, I'm not using a Wix Installer, so I managed to create the shortcut in an other way: **IShellLinkW**.
So far, I succeed in sending a Toast. but I can't get a callback when operating on it.
My create short cut code:

```
using (PropVariant appId = new PropVariant(_aumid))
{
    ErrorHelper.VerifySucceeded(newShortcutProperties.SetValue
    (
        new PropertyKey(new Guid("9F4C2855-9F79-4B39-A8D0-E1D42DE1D5F3"), 5), appId)
    );
}
```

It works well,so the **SetValue** method should be OK
I think I can hock the callback method with its GUID in the same way:

```
var toastclass = typeof(T).GUID.ToString();
using (PropVariant toastid = new PropVariant(toastclass))
{
    toastid.SetEnum(VarEnum.VT_CLSID);
    ErrorHelper.VerifySucceeded
    (
        newShortcutProperties.SetValue
        (
            new PropertyKey(new Guid("9F4C2855-9F79-4B39-A8D0-E1D42DE1D5F3"), 26), toastid
        )
    );
}
ErrorHelper.VerifySucceeded(newShortcutProperties.Commit());
```

I register it this way

```
// Register type
var regService = new RegistrationServices();

regService.RegisterTypeForComClients
(
    typeof(T),
    RegistrationClassContext.LocalServer,
    RegistrationConnectionType.MultipleUse
);

_registeredActivator = true;
```

but finally the callback method not firing

```
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(INotificationActivationCallback))]
[Guid("9a88b91d-f9c4-4c63-91dd-175c2c2cb458"), ComVisible(true)]
public class AreaIconToast : NotificationActivator
{
```

Answer (score 1):

**Finally** I solved this problem, I find it is beacuse I pass CLSID in string format when creating the shortcut,but the right way is to pass it as byte[] ,so that's why the callback method don't work.